# Finding the distribution of a piecewise function of a Gamma random variable

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution, function, piecewise-linear

Let random variable $X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$. I want to derive the distribution of $Y$, where:

$$
Y = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            a X - k & \quad X \geq \frac{k}{a} \\
            0 & \quad \text{else}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

where $a$ and $k$ are constants. Any suggestions? Can I use method of transformations and a truncated Gamma distribution somehow?

Comment: What's piecewise about this problem?

Comment: The function of the rv that I want to transform to is piecewise.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a simple mixture model. Find the probability of Qs=0 response as a point mass first. Use Jacobian method to find Qs as if there wasn't a condition. Truncate that distribution at 0, and scale by the complement of the 0 probability so that it all adds to 1.

Comment: Thanks! @wolfies I agree, that would be clearer. I'm new to the stats world.

Comment: You can further simplify the question by noting (1) $aX$ has a $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,a\beta)$ distribution (assuming $\beta$ is a scale parameter); (2) the distribution of $aX-k$ is that of $aX$ shifted by $k;$ and (3) $Y=\max(0,aX-k).$   At this point the problem is so simple that you ought to consider applying the definition: compute $\Pr(Y \le y)$ for (a) $y\gt 0$ and (b) $y\le 0.$ Neither requires any calculation.

Comment: The foregoing series of comments and edits to the question nicely illustrates the benefits of a general procedure strongly advocated on [SO]--it's therefore not of a statistical nature at all: *present a minimal reproducible example of your problem.*  In statistics (and mathematics generally, as well as in programming) that approach frequently solves the problem, obviating any need even to ask it. :-)